# In Javascript, is there a way to call a var in another .js file like in Java?

Tags: javascript, file, var

In Java if I wanna call a var from another file in the same folder I can just call the file name and then the var I wanna call. But, I'm looking for a similar thing in Javascript. Please let me know if there is. For Example:

FileName: wordBank.java

```
int wordCount = 0;
```

*Then in the Other File*
I can call that wordCount by saying:

```
wordBank.wordCount = 1; // (assuming wordCount is public)
```

So is there a way to mimic this code in Javascript?

Comment: I think you have some misunderstanding on how things actually work. You are not referencing a file. You are referencing a instance of object. Object shares file name because its good practice. 

In JS you can do same. But how exactly depends on the JS version you are using. In some cases you can use import and export keywords. Or you can place it into global scope. Or if you manually import into HTML then it just works. Or you can use require keyword (closest to refrencing a file).  Or maybe you are using some framework and some bundler. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_modules.asp

Comment: There are modules(import/export), there is reading files and evaling them, there is require, there is including the script into your html file. Can't really say without knowing your javascript environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly export and import it like so with es6
wordBank.js:

```
export const wordCount = 0;
```

otherFile.js:

```
import { wordCount } from "./wordBank"
console.log(wordCount)
```

However, there is no specific way to outright mutate a variable passes between files. You could do something like this:

```
let wordCount = 0;
export function setWordCount(value) {
    wordCount = value
}
```

then in the other file:

```
import { setWordCount } from "./wordBank"

setWordCount(1)
```